# How can I make sure IE trusts all internal servers?

Tags: .net, iis, iframe, windows-authentication

I want to ensure that Internet Explorer on all domain computers trust all domain servers.

The specific problem I have is with our on premises installation of Dynamics CRM 2011. I have the requirement to show a page within an iframe, this page uses Windows Authentication to authenticate users and audit actions.

When I load the view with the iframe, out of the box, IE will seemingly place the site in its restricted zone and ultimately I get a 401 error.

I have created a test site with the same Windows Update configuration to load in the iframe and explicitly adding this to the trusted sites zone works but this is a pain to do on each machine and is a work around. As far as I’m concerned, each client should trust our internal servers and should fall into the Intranet Zone.

How can I force the behaviour I require?

Comment: This is one option we could use but seems like a work around. The ideal solution is that clients trust all the servers on the domain negating the need to use GP.

Comment: Don't agree with your comment on negate the need for GP.  This is just a comment not meant to be argumentative.  A default OS install is not aware it is in a domain.  I would not want joining a domain to automatically trust all servers in a domain.  I don't see it as a work around - I see it as exactly what Group Policy is designed to do.  If you see it differently then I respect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure these settings via Group Policy.  Computer Config>>Administative Templates>>Windows Components>>Internet Explorer>>Internet Control Panel>>Security Page  then look at the Site to Zone Assignment List policy.